# In Emacs, how can I syntax-highlight a text in a C mode buffer matching a certain regular expression?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

By default Emacs will not highlight constants, struct members, function calls etc (unless inside the definition). I am talking about C major mode here.

I want some basic highlighting, just based on text matching. For example, A word containing only upper case and underscore, [A-Z_]+, for example SOME_CONST, is a constant (unless otherwise highlighted). Similarly, I can match for [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\s*( as function call; ->[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* as a struct member etc.

How can I do this emacs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the elisp function that you want is font-lock-add-keywords.  I've added the following to my .emacs and gotten what I think you want for upper case words:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode '("\\<\[A-Z_\]\+\\>"))
```

You'd have to add a bit more to handle integer constants.  Some of the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html) around this warns that if you're not intelligent about your regular expressions it can slow things down dramatically, and that you should use regexp-opt for matching multiple keywords.

The part that was a bit confusing for me is that the argument to font-lock-add-keywords can be a regular expression.

Comment: This works! Now any idea how I can enable this for the C major mode so it works with C++, h, java etc files too ?

Comment: I think you're going to have to make multiple calls for each one.  The documentation for font-lock-add-keywords does say that it should work for derived modes, and that if it does not, you should file a bug report.

Comment: There is `c-mode-common-hook` which runs for C, C++, java, and a few others.